# ERR trap gets a return code of 1; there is no stderr text I can find for a statement "(( kIdx++ ))" why?

Tags: bash, error-handling

My code is as follows:

The error statement moved befored the fxSETprintf call so kIdx would match the ${kIdx} argument number in the function call.  There was also comment removal and revision.  Functionally nothing changed.

The error statement is line 432  -- there are debug statements and comments before that.

The trap code starts at line 466

If the code ran without a trap it would appear to work perfectly (note kIdx increments in the loop as desired)

If you

1. save this file as demo3.sh
2. run from a terminal window "source demo3.sh "demo3" "--test"
3. the functions are loaded
4. near the bottom of demo3.sh
5. the call to "fxBASHdump "${BASH_SUBSHELL}" "${LINENO}" "${BASH_COMMAND}"
6. creates the shown output

```
#!/bin/bash

###########
#
#   My coding standards for scripted code
#       1)  I tend to use tabs instead of spaces between items
#           A)  I have learned this is undesurable when cutting and pasting code into a terminal window.
#               1)  I have chosen to live with that quirk.
#           B)  I set tabs to be 4 spaces
#               1) the gnome bash terminal window appears to have fixed tab width of 8 spaces.
#                   a)  I have chosen to live with that quirk.
#       2)  I quote just about everything
#           A)  for items where substitution is not desired or not needed use single quotes (')
#           b)  for items requiring substitution use double quotes (")
#           c)  GOTCHA: the following results in a string the length of 2 containing two single quotes
#                       (using Ubuntu 20.04 on 3/15/2022 hardware RasPi 4B 8GB)
#                   local lVar="${5:-''}"
#                       the same thing with double quotes generates a set (vs unset) string length of 0
#                   local lVar="${5:-""}"
#                       so I use double quotes, in this case, that produce the desired results.
#       3)  I put braces around most, if not all, variables
#           A)  I used many array references early in my coding and was leaving them out
#               1)  including them at all times seems to have no negative effect
#       4)  when using single or double parens I tend to provide either a space or tab immediately inside both parens
#           A)  largely because I like the readability and it appears to be acceptable
#
#
#
#       A)  some statements have specific formats
#           1)  trap statements
#               a)  in order to extract bash source statements (not reported by the system based on current observation)
#                       trap\t'[statement]'\t[trapname]
#               b)  I believe "$( cut -d '\t' -f2 <<< "$( trap -p [trapname] )"
#                   1)  will return the trap source statement
#
###########
#
#   WARNING THIS CODE CONTAINS TRAPS
#       modifications to the PS4 system variable
#       and potentialy other items that can affect your system
#
#       to the best of my knowledge ending and restarting the terminal window
#           should eliminate the changes to the system.
#
#
###########


set     +o  xtrace


shopt   -s  checkhash
shopt   -s  expand_aliases
shopt   -s  extdebug

set     -o  errtrace
set     -o  functrace


vxScr="${1:-""}"        #   {name}
vxOpt="${2:-""}"        #   "--test" or ""


##########
#
#   axPS
#       output line prefixes
#
#           axPS    -   references the current line
#
#       Usage in fxOUT
#
#           if      [[  -z  "${lRc}"    ]]; then
#               lPS:-"$( axPS "${lId}" )"
#           else
#               lPS:-"$( axPS "${lId}" "${lRc}" )"
#           fi
#
#       Arguments   (see fxOUT for argument details)
#
##########

alias   axPS='printf %c:%u:' 

fxOUT()
{
    case    "$1"    in
        (-h | --help)
            fxOUT   'M'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '###########'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#  fxOUT'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#      ex: fxOUT   [Id]    {Rc}    {Text}'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#      Arguments'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#          Id      With Rc values  (see fxRcID --help)'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      E   -   error       Flg=7'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      W   -   warning     Flg-7'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      0   -   Rc=0        Flg=4'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      R   -   fxTrapERR   Flg=4'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                  Without Rc values'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      M   - manual        Flg=3'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      D   - stdout        Flg=3'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      ?   - read/select   Flg=3'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      d   - debug display Flg={2 4 6}'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      T   - trap          Flg=4'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      X   - BASH_COMMAND  Flg=4'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      x   - xtrace        Flg=4'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#          Rc      -   BASH Return/Exit Codes'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#              NOTE: A webpage identified the probable known system range'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      system codes        1-63'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      user error tbd      64-79'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      user error codes    80-87'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      fxTrapDEBUG (skip)  88'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      user warning codes  89-96'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      user warning tbd    97-113'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      system codes        114-255'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#          Text    -   Text to display'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                          cannot contain escaped characters'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                          fxOUT without text prints blank line'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                          use actual tab instead of '\''\t'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '###########'
            fxOUT   'M'
            ;;

        (*)
            local   lId="${1:-""}"
            local   lRc="${2:-""}"
            local   lText="${3:-""}"

            local   lPS=''

            if      [[  -z  "${lRc}"    ]]; then
                lPS="$( axPS "${lId}" )"
            else
                lPS="$( axPS "${lId}" "${lRc}" )"
            fi

            printf      '%s\t%s\n'  "${lPS}"    "${lText}"
            ;;
    esac

    return  '0'
}


##########
#
#   fxSETprintf
#
##########

fxSETprintf()
{
    case    "$1"    in
        (-h | --help)
            fxOUT   'M'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '###########'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#  fxSETprintf'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#      Displays the set status and value of the reference variable'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#          fxSET[printf    [VarName] [RefName] [AdjName]'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#      Arguments'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#          VarName -   display name for variable'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      (max 20 char)'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#          RefName -   actual name for variable'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      (max 20 char)'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                      ex: '\''FUNCNAME[0]'\'''
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#          AdjName -   adjusted name for variable'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                          The adjustment is for the extra level or three arguments'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                              created by this function call when printing the BASH variables'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '###########'
            fxOUT   'M'
            ;;

        (*)
            local   lVarName="${1:-""}"     #   display name of variable
            local   lRefName="${2:-""}"     #   reference name of variable
            local   lAdjName="${3:-""}"     #   adjusted name for  variable

            local   lSet=''

            #
            #           explanation testing for an unset variable requires two steps
            #       Step 1      [[ -x '${var}" ]]
            #                       True    is empty string (set) and unset (not initialized)
            #                       False   is set the string contains characters
            #
            #       Step 2          after step one we only have zero length items
            #                           the dash (-) above says
            #                               to set an unset variable with what follows (_)
            #                   [[ -n "${var-_}" ]]
            #                       True    is an unset variable it contains '_' length 1
            #                       False   is a set variable with a zero length string ""
            #
            #       GOTCHA
            #           coding the test as follows yields an ALWAYS set variable
            #   v="${FUNCNAME[0]}"
            #   if [[ -z "${v}" && -n "${v-_}" ]]; then
            #
            #       The following works for a hard coded variable
            #   if [[ -z "${FUNCNAME[0]}" && -n "${FUNCNAME[0]-_}" ]]; then
            #
            #       or
            #
            #       The code below works if lAdjName is set as follows
            #           NOTE:   no dollar sign ($) or braces {}
            #   lAdjName='FUNCNAME[0]'
            #

            if [[ -z "${!lAdjName}" && -n "${!lAdjName-_}" ]]; then
                lSet='unset'
            else
                lSet='set'
            fi

            local   lText=''
            lText="$( printf '%-20s%-8s%s=%s' "${lVarName}" "${lSet}" "${lRefName}" "${!lAdjName}" )"


            fxOUT   'd' ''  "${lText}"
            ;;
    esac

    return  "0"
}


##########
#
#   fxBASHdump
#
##########

fxBASHdump ()
{
    case    "$1"    in
        (-h | --help)
            fxOUT   'M'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '###########'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#  fxBASHdump'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#      Dumps the  BASH Execution Stack'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#      fxBASHdump  "${BASH_SUBSHELL}"  "${LINENO}" "${BASH_COMMAND}"'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                  "${BASH_SUBSHELL}"  - the subshell level number'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                                            0 is main shell'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                                          > 0 is sub shell'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                  "${LINENO}"         - in this case the line number'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                                          from the console (terminal command line)'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                                              or'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                                          source code'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                  "${BASH_SUBSHELL}"  - the bash command'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#                                          in this case the call to fxBASHdump'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '#'
            fxOUT   'M' ''  '###########'
            fxOUT   'M'
            ;;

        (*)
            local   lSub="${1:-"${BASH_SUBSHELL}"}"
            local   lLNo="${2:-"${LINENO}"}"
            local   lCmd="${3:-"${BASH_COMMAND}"}"

            local   l='0'
            local   lMax="${#BASH_ARGC[@]}"

            local   k='0'
            local   kIdx='0'
            local   kRef='0'
            local   kAdj='0'
            local   kCum='0'


            fxOUT       'd'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#      The first three variables point to an instruction in fxSETprintf'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#          if used directly in the function.'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#          This was both expected and undesired.'
            fxOUT       'd'

            fxSETprintf 'BASH_SUBSHELL' 'BASH_SUBSHELL' 'BASH_SUBSHELL'
            fxSETprintf 'LINENO'        'LINENO'        'LINENO'
            fxSETprintf "BASH_COMMAND"  "BASH_COMMAND"  'BASH_COMMAND'

            fxOUT       'd'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#  The following three items were passed as arguments to preserve their state'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#      when tested with all traps disabled'
            fxOUT       'd'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#          fxBASHdump'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#              allowing the values to default inside the function'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#              also yields expected and undesired results'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#                  where LINENO points to one command in fxBASHdump'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#                  where BASH_COMMAND references the following command'
            fxOUT       'd'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#          fxBASHdump "${BASH_SUBSHELL}" "${LINENO}" "${BASH_COMMAND}"'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#              The results reflect the fxBASHdump command, the desired result'
            fxOUT       'd'

            fxOUT       'd'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#  Based on the next two commands I believe'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#      if BASH_COMMAND is passed as lSub; it returns'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#          the valid subshell for the fxBASHdump command.'
            fxOUT       'd'

            fxSETprintf 'BASH_SUBSHELL' 'BASH_SUBSHELL' 'lSub'

            fxOUT       'd'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#  This is the LINENO'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#      If LINENO is passed as lLNo; it returns'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#          the console line number'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#              of the fxBASHdump command, as desired'
            fxOUT       'd'

            fxSETprintf 'LINENO'        'LINENO'        'lLNo'

            fxOUT       'd'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#  This is the source command (statement)'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#      If BASH_COMMAND is passed as lCmd; it returns '
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#          the fxBASHdump command, as desired'
            fxOUT       'd'

            fxSETprintf "BASH_COMMAND"  "BASH_COMMAND"  'lCmd'

            fxOUT       'd'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#  This is the name of the script interpreter'
            fxOUT       'd'

            fxSETprintf "BASH_ARGV0"    "BASH_ARGV0d"   "BASH_ARGV0"

            fxOUT       'd'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '##########'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '#  The following items are a backtrace of functions, scripts, and commands'
            fxOUT       'd' ''  '##########'
            fxOUT       'd'

            for ((l=0; l<lMax; l++))
            do
                case    "$l"    in
                    (0)
                        fxOUT   'd'
                        fxOUT   'd' ''  '#  This entry is for fxBASHdump \(the function printing this\).'
                        fxOUT   'd' ''  '#      BASH_LINENO[0] is the LINENO of the call to fXtrapBASH.'
                        fxOUT   'd' ''  '#      That line number is found in BASH_SOURCE[1] \(see below\).'
                        fxOUT   'd'

                        ;;

                    ( $(( lMax - 2)) )
                        fxOUT   'd'
                        fxOUT   'd' ''  '#  This is probably the command line entry that started this execution.'
                        fxOUT   'd' ''  '#      BASH_LINENO['"$(( lMax - 2))"'] is the LINENO of the initial command.'
                        fxOUT   'd' ''  '#      The unset entry in BASH_SOURCE['"$(( lMax - 1))"'] \(see below\).'
                        fxOUT   'd' ''  '#          I believe indicates a console command.'
                        fxOUT   'd'
                        ;;

                    ( $(( lMax - 1)) )
                        fxOUT   'd'
                        fxOUT   'd' ''  '#  This is probably an entry for an idle BASH interpreter.'
                        fxOUT   'd'
                        ;;

                    (*)
                        fxOUT   'd'
                        fxOUT   'd' ''  '#  This entry represents the parent call that created the'
                        fxOUT   'd' ''  '#      previously printed level.'
                        fxOUT   'd'
                        ;;
                esac

                fxOUT   'd'

                local   lAdj="$(( l + 1 ))"     # offset for the one level added by fxSETprintf function call

                fxSETprintf "BASH_SOURCE[${l}]" "BASH_SOURCE[${l}]" "BASH_SOURCE[${lAdj}]"

                fxSETprintf "FUNCNAME[${l}]"    "FUNCNAME[${l}]"    "FUNCNAME[${lAdj}]"

                fxSETprintf "BASH_LINENO[${l}]" "BASH_LINENO[${l}]" "BASH_LINENO[${lAdj}]"

                fxSETprintf "BASH_ARGC[${l}]"   "BASH_ARGC[${l}]"   "BASH_ARGC[${lAdj}]"

                    #   Notice below that BASH_ARGV is a single array for all execution levels.
                    #       the parameters are stored in decending order in BASH_ARGV
                    #       this code reverses that for display purposes
                    #       the ref=name printed shows the physical location in the BASH_ARGV
                k="${BASH_ARGC[$l]}"
                kIdx='0'

                if      [[  "${k}"  -gt 0   ]]; then
                    fxOUT   'd'
                    fxOUT   'd' ''  '#  The location in BASH_ARGV is shown in ref={name}  \(see below\)'
                    fxOUT   'd' ''
                    fxOUT   'd' ''  '#  I know bash arrays cannot have two indexes'
                    fxOUT   'd' ''  '#      but logically reflects the situation'
                    fxOUT   'd'
                    fxOUT   'd' ''  '#      Notice how the ref index continue to increment '
                    fxOUT   'd' ''  '#          as the levels are displayed'
                    fxOUT   'd'
                fi

                while   [ "${k}" -gt 0  ]
                do
                    (( k-- ))

                        #  see above 
                        #   line 283    local kIdx='0'    (also tried as "0" - no difference)
                        #   line 402    kIdx='0'          (also tried as "0" - no difference)
                        # the following two lines were added for debug purposes -- not intended to be in the final
                        #
                        # kIdx seems to be messed up for the first pass =0 however it increments properly
                        #       without a ERR trap this code would appear to function correctly.
                    fxSETprintf "kIdx"                      "kIdx"                  "kIdx"
                    echo "kIdx=\"${kIdx}\""

                        #   I added the 2>$1 in the testing process to try to force syserr to display
                        #       there appears to be no syserr message.
                    (( kIdx++ )) 2>&1

                    kRef="$(( kCum + k ))"
                    kAdj="$(( kRef + 3 ))"   # 3 arguments to fxSETprintf

                    fxSETprintf "BASH_ARGV[${l} ${kIdx}]"   "BASH_ARGV[${kRef}]"    "BASH_ARGV[${kAdj}]"

                done
                kCum=$(( kCum + ${BASH_ARGC[${l}]} ))
            done

            fxOUT   'd'
            ;;
    esac

    return '0'

}

export  -f  fxOUT
export  -f  fxSETprintf
export  -f  fxBASHdump


#############################################################################################################################################


##########
#
#   Initialize Trap functions
#
##########


fxTrapERR()
{
    local   lTrap='ERR'
            #   the following timestamp is generated in fxOUT for the print lines
            #       uncomment of required for the trap itself
    ### local   lTS=''                                      #   timestamp of trap initiation
    ### lTS="$( date -u '+%H%M%S%03N' )"                    #   {timestamp}
    local   lLvl="${1:-"0"}"                            #   "${#BASH_ARGC[@]}"  {current command execution level}
    local   lSub="${2:-"0"}"                            #   "${BASH_SUBSHELL}"  {current subshell level}
    local   lSrc="${3:-""}"                             #   "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" {script that contains the source}
    local   lSNm=''                                     #   {scriptname}
    lSNm="$( basename "$lSrc" '.sh' )"                  #   {filename portion of "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"}
    local   lFNm="${4:-""}"                             #   "${FUNCNAME[0]}"    {function name, if in function}
    ### local   lRcLNo="${vxLNo}"                           #   "${LINENO}"         {previous, may not need}
    local   lLNo="${5:-"0"}"                            #   "${LINENO}"         {current line number}
    local   lCmd="${6:-""}"                             #   "${BASH_COMMAND}"   {current source command}
        #   BASH_LINENO may only be used to verify the parent
    local   lBLN="${7:-"0"}"                            #   "${BASH_LINENO[0]}" {line number of parent script/function/command}
        #   the return code of the current or prior command depending on the trap initiated
    local   lRc="${8:-"0"}"                             #   "$?"

    fxOUT   'E' "${lRc}"    "Trap=\"${lTrap}\" Lvl=\"${lLvl}\" Sub=\"${lSub}\" Src=\"${lSrc}\" SNm=\"${lSNm}\" FNm=\"${lFNm}\" LNo=\"${lLNo}\""  # BLN=\"${lBLN"}\""
    fxOUT   'E' "${lRc}"    "Cmd=\"${lCmd}\""

    read -rp 'pause'

    return  '0'
}

##########
#
#   Enable Trap functions
#
##########


trap    'fxTrapERR    "${#BASH_ARGC[@]}" "${BASH_SUBSHELL}" "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" "${FUNCNAME[0]}" "${LINENO}" "${BASH_COMMAND}" "${BASH_LINENO[0]}" "$?"'    ERR


export  PS4='x:     '

### set     -o  xtrace


if      [[  "${vxOpt}"  ==  '--test'    ]]; then
     fxBASHdump "${BASH_SUBSHELL}" "${LINENO}" "${BASH_COMMAND}"
fi

return  '0'
```

The first section of output that shows the problem is:
In this section the bold/italic code is debug output and the ERR trap output.  kIdx incremented correctly and displays properly in the non-debug/trap lines.  All evidence indicates the (( kIdx++ )) statement created it's expected output without a problem.  Why am I trapping an error here?

```
d:0:
d:0:    BASH_SOURCE[0]      set     BASH_SOURCE[0]=demo3.sh
d:0:    FUNCNAME[0]         set     FUNCNAME[0]=fxBASHdump
d:0:    BASH_LINENO[0]      set     BASH_LINENO[0]=511
d:0:    BASH_ARGC[0]        set     BASH_ARGC[0]=3
d:0:
d:0:    #       The location in BASH_ARGV is shown in ref={name}  \(see below\)
d:0:
d:0:    #       I know bash arrays cannot have two indexes
d:0:    #               but logically reflects the situation
d:0:
d:0:    #               Notice how the ref index continue to increment 
d:0:    #                       as the levels are displayed
d:0:
***d:0:    kIdx                set     kIdx=0
kIdx="0"
E:1:    Trap="ERR" Lvl="3" Sub="0" Src="demo3.sh" SNm="demo3" FNm="fxBASHdump" LNo="432"
E:1:    Cmd="(( kIdx++ ))"
pause***
d:0:    BASH_ARGV[0 1]      set     BASH_ARGV[2]=0
***d:0:    kIdx                set     kIdx=1
kIdx="1"***
d:0:    BASH_ARGV[0 2]      set     BASH_ARGV[1]=511
***d:0:    kIdx                set     kIdx=2
kIdx="2"***
d:0:    BASH_ARGV[0 3]      set     BASH_ARGV[0]=fxBASHdump "${BASH_SUBSHELL}" "${LINENO}" "${BASH_COMMAND}"
d:0:
```

The full output is as follows:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/pool/src/trap/scr/old$ source demo3.sh demo --test
d:0:
d:0:    #               The first three variables point to an instruction in fxSETprintf
d:0:    #                       if used directly in the function.
d:0:    #                       This was both expected and undesired.
d:0:
d:0:    BASH_SUBSHELL       set     BASH_SUBSHELL=1
d:0:    LINENO              set     LINENO=229
d:0:    BASH_COMMAND        set     BASH_COMMAND=printf '%-20s%-8s%s=%s' "${lVarName}" "${lSet}" "${lRefName}" "${!lAdjName}"
d:0:
d:0:    #       The following three items were passed as arguments to preserve their state
d:0:    #               when tested with all traps disabled
d:0:
d:0:    #                       fxBASHdump
d:0:    #                               allowing the values to default inside the function
d:0:    #                               also yields expected and undesired results
d:0:    #                                       where LINENO points to one command in fxBASHdump
d:0:    #                                       where BASH_COMMAND references the following command
d:0:
d:0:    #                       fxBASHdump "${BASH_SUBSHELL}" "${LINENO}" "${BASH_COMMAND}"
d:0:    #                               The results reflect the fxBASHdump command, the desired result
d:0:
d:0:
d:0:    #       Based on the next two commands I believe
d:0:    #               if BASH_COMMAND is passed as lSub; it returns
d:0:    #                       the valid subshell for the fxBASHdump command.
d:0:
d:0:    BASH_SUBSHELL       set     BASH_SUBSHELL=0
d:0:
d:0:    #       This is the LINENO
d:0:    #               If LINENO is passed as lLNo; it returns
d:0:    #                       the console line number
d:0:    #                               of the fxBASHdump command, as desired
d:0:
d:0:    LINENO              set     LINENO=511
d:0:
d:0:    #       This is the source command (statement)
d:0:    #               If BASH_COMMAND is passed as lCmd; it returns 
d:0:    #                       the fxBASHdump command, as desired
d:0:
d:0:    BASH_COMMAND        set     BASH_COMMAND=fxBASHdump "${BASH_SUBSHELL}" "${LINENO}" "${BASH_COMMAND}"
d:0:
d:0:    #       This is the name of the script interpreter
d:0:
d:0:    BASH_ARGV0          set     BASH_ARGV0d=/usr/bin/bash
d:0:
d:0:    ##########
d:0:    #       The following items are a backtrace of functions, scripts, and commands
d:0:    ##########
d:0:
d:0:
d:0:    #       This entry is for fxBASHdump \(the function printing this\).
d:0:    #               BASH_LINENO[0] is the LINENO of the call to fXtrapBASH.
d:0:    #               That line number is found in BASH_SOURCE[1] \(see below\).
d:0:
d:0:
d:0:    BASH_SOURCE[0]      set     BASH_SOURCE[0]=demo3.sh
d:0:    FUNCNAME[0]         set     FUNCNAME[0]=fxBASHdump
d:0:    BASH_LINENO[0]      set     BASH_LINENO[0]=511
d:0:    BASH_ARGC[0]        set     BASH_ARGC[0]=3
d:0:
d:0:    #       The location in BASH_ARGV is shown in ref={name}  \(see below\)
d:0:
d:0:    #       I know bash arrays cannot have two indexes
d:0:    #               but logically reflects the situation
d:0:
d:0:    #               Notice how the ref index continue to increment 
d:0:    #                       as the levels are displayed
d:0:
d:0:    kIdx                set     kIdx=0
kIdx="0"
E:1:    Trap="ERR" Lvl="3" Sub="0" Src="demo3.sh" SNm="demo3" FNm="fxBASHdump" LNo="432"
E:1:    Cmd="(( kIdx++ ))"
pause
d:0:    BASH_ARGV[0 1]      set     BASH_ARGV[2]=0
d:0:    kIdx                set     kIdx=1
kIdx="1"
d:0:    BASH_ARGV[0 2]      set     BASH_ARGV[1]=511
d:0:    kIdx                set     kIdx=2
kIdx="2"
d:0:    BASH_ARGV[0 3]      set     BASH_ARGV[0]=fxBASHdump "${BASH_SUBSHELL}" "${LINENO}" "${BASH_COMMAND}"
d:0:
d:0:    #       This is probably the command line entry that started this execution.
d:0:    #               BASH_LINENO[1] is the LINENO of the initial command.
d:0:    #               The unset entry in BASH_SOURCE[2] \(see below\).
d:0:    #                       I believe indicates a console command.
d:0:
d:0:
d:0:    BASH_SOURCE[1]      set     BASH_SOURCE[1]=demo3.sh
d:0:    FUNCNAME[1]         set     FUNCNAME[1]=source
d:0:    BASH_LINENO[1]      set     BASH_LINENO[1]=6
d:0:    BASH_ARGC[1]        set     BASH_ARGC[1]=2
d:0:
d:0:    #       The location in BASH_ARGV is shown in ref={name}  \(see below\)
d:0:
d:0:    #       I know bash arrays cannot have two indexes
d:0:    #               but logically reflects the situation
d:0:
d:0:    #               Notice how the ref index continue to increment 
d:0:    #                       as the levels are displayed
d:0:
d:0:    kIdx                set     kIdx=0
kIdx="0"
E:1:    Trap="ERR" Lvl="3" Sub="0" Src="demo3.sh" SNm="demo3" FNm="fxBASHdump" LNo="432"
E:1:    Cmd="(( kIdx++ ))"
pause
d:0:    BASH_ARGV[1 1]      set     BASH_ARGV[4]=demo
d:0:    kIdx                set     kIdx=1
kIdx="1"
d:0:    BASH_ARGV[1 2]      set     BASH_ARGV[3]=--test
d:0:
d:0:    #       This is probably an entry for an idle BASH interpreter.
d:0:
d:0:
d:0:    BASH_SOURCE[2]      unset   BASH_SOURCE[2]=
d:0:    FUNCNAME[2]         unset   FUNCNAME[2]=
d:0:    BASH_LINENO[2]      unset   BASH_LINENO[2]=
d:0:    BASH_ARGC[2]        set     BASH_ARGC[2]=0
d:0:
ubuntu@ubuntu:/pool/src/trap/scr/old$
```

Comment: The (( kIdx++ )) appears to be executing successfully.  If that is the case why am I getting the report of a return code of 1 for the execution of the command the first time through the loop for each level in the BASH trace variables?.  The report of an error by the ERR trap is the problem.

Comment: I fixed a logic flaw BASH_ARGV0 is not an array.  It is now treated as the interpreter program name.  I am also rewriting this to include all code in the DEBUG and ERR traps no functions calling out to see if the problem goes away,  It is a way out guess as to what the problem is but I am trying something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deal of trial and error, I found that the `(( kIdx-- ))` statement appears to be an intermittent cause of the error.  It works in the main script and fails selectively in the trap.  Replacement of the instruction with `kIdx="$(( kIdx - 1 ))"` in the trap eliminated the ERR trap's pointing to the instruction in the first pass of the first loop.  It appears to be a successful workaround for the issue should you encounter it.  I have rewritten this code several times in the process. In the current version Kidx in this version was replaced with k; but the workaround solved the issue.

The intermittent nature of the error with the original statement is when as noted above the tested value of the expression is zero a return code of 1 is generated.

Answer (score 0):

An "error" is just a non-zero return status.  It isn't always an error.

From `man bash`:

> `((expression))`
>
> The  expression  is evaluated according to the rules described below under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  If the value of
> the expression is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1.  This is exactly  equivalent
> to let "expression".

`(( 0 ))` has a return status of 1, which signals an "error", so a variable equal to 0 will trigger the `ERR` trap.

The command `false` always does the same.

`(( 0 )) || true` (`||` meaning *or*), or the shorter form `(( 0 )) ||:`  suppresses the "error".

Comment: Does that mean a condition code setting in an arithmetic operation will cause an ERR trap to initiate?  is there any documentation on sorting out real errors from condition codes in the ERR trap?  Might it have to do with the existence or non-existence of a stderr message? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, unless followed by `||` then something with a zero return code, such as `true`.  You need to tell the shell yourself what to ignore.   Read [Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).